# Pandas DataFrame.to_latex() doesn't recognize column_format

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating latex tables from Pandas DataFrames using the .to_latex() command. According to its [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) it has a column_format keyword argument, but when I try to set it to 'cccc' I get an error:

```
to_latex() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cols_format'
```

Why does this happen?

EDIT: The error message I get is actually

```
TypeError: to_latex() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column_format'
```

Comment: Could you show your dataframe which you are trying to save?

Comment: show your code, I don't see `cols_format` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword argument is `column_format` NOT `cols_format`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using column_format, I don't know why I wrote cols_format in my question.